# Looking for a book series about every single fantasy trope ever

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, arthurian

A group of people from Arthurian times, including king Arthur himself find themselves in another world/land and they must rebuild a city after a war (??) has ravaged the lands? (Yay portals)
Then there is a time jump and the main character lives in this city and is on a quest, with friends.
He refuses to use a sword so wields a quarterstaff always. There is some sort of soul bond on a sword.
But elves have made a sword that only he can carry: the sun sword (or similar).
Plus there are giant telekinetic (?) spiders or something. 
And ice men! They are trying to fight and main dude needs the sword to kill them.
There are also corrupt nobles.

Think of every trope in fantasy and add it to this series and you'll know what we are trying to find.

There is 4 or 5 books in the series. 
They were read last about 4 years ago, so nothing new.
It's definitely not Game of Thrones.

I know this is vague as heck but trying to help a friend who read the first 4 books 4 or 5 years and wanted to read the 5th that hadn't at the time even written yet.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: "They were read last about 4 years ago, so nothing new." Thank you for making me feel old. :)

Comment: There are a lot of old things like Guy Gabriel Kay's _Fionavar Tapestry_ that kind-of match this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the Frostborn series by Jonathan Moeller.  It has fifteen volumes.

The ice men are the Frostborn of the title -- the main villains. The humans are on the world because Mordred's bastard son used a portal to get them to this world after the fall of Camelot.

The hero Ridmark was convicted of cowardice and forbidden to carry a sword; he carries a quarterstaff instead, but he does in the end find the sword that makes him the Dragon Knight.

Certain dark elves made various spider-like creatures for various purposes.

Comment: for the lazy >>> The Frostborn Series – Jonathan Moeller, Pulp Writer — https://www.jonathanmoeller.com/writer/?page_id=3536 <<< //// the `Pulp Writer` tag is a giggle ... [*grin*]

Comment: Single book only, but Heinlein's "The Number of the Beast' (1980) touches on this subject matter too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_of_the_Beast_(novel)

Comment: Mary coming though with the winner! Thank you so much everyone who made a suggestion but Jonathan Moeller was the correct author. Who incidentally, was a lot more prolific than thought.